# OpenCL - Same code, Correct on Apple + Xcode incorrect on Win XP + MSVS 2008 + Nvidia CUDA 5

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I am running the same OpenCL code on a MacPro equiped with a Nvidia GTX580 running either of the following:

- OS X 10.8.2 with Xcode 4.6
- Windows XP 32 bit with  Visual C++ 2008 enterprise and Nvidia CUDA toolkit 5.0

However I get the wrong results in Win XP.

To define the number of work items used I specify the work group size (192), the number of workgroups (256) and set the global number of work items used as work group size x workgroups (192 x 256 = 49152).

When I run this on the Apple platform all my results are correct however when I run it on the Win XP platform I get a result which is out by a factor of 1/8.

Doing some checks I got the GPU to store what it thinks is the global size and it reports the expected number as 49152 however if I instead get the first work item of each workgroup to atomically add the local size to a counter I only get 6144, exactly 1/8 of the global size.

This problem seems to be a function of the number of work items set and if I set the workgroup size to 32 or 64 I will get the correct answer (when the workgroup size is held constant at 192). However for any other values I have this problem and my result may be off by a factor of 1/8, 1/4 or 1/2 depending on the number of work items used.

Is there any reason of this to occur like 32bit addressing limits or aggressive optimisations in the NVidia library?

Comment: GPGPU technologies are not exactly a model of stability. If you really can't find the problem it wouldn't be too far-fetched to assume an OpenCL runtime bug, did you try different runtime versions?

Comment: I haven't tried another runtime yet, I will try with the CUDA 4 drivers.

Comment: I have tried with the CUDA 4.1 toolkit on win XP 32 bit and CUDA 5 toolkit on windows 7 64 bit and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Apple OpenCL library global write only memory is initialised to 0 for numeric data types, in the windows Nvidia library global write only memory is not initialised.

Therefore when counters in global memory were incremented there starting value was undefined. When this was suspected a quick and foolish initialisation loop was put at the start of the kernel, this of course resulted in workgroups executed later zeroing the results workgroups executed earlier giving the observed reduction in the result in proportion to the number of kernels executed on each compute unit.